# Почему данные sql не выводятся в html?

Tags: java

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Я помещаю список в sql таблицу, затем с помощью селекта достаю данные из таблицы и прикрепляю их к html, но при загрузке html страницы данные из sql таблицы не видны.

Вот контроллер:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

@GetMapping("/")
public String greeting(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("name", "132");
    return "greeting";
}
@RequestMapping("/main")
public String main(Model model) {

    List<Valute> valuteValues = new ArrayList<>();


    try {
        DocumentBuilder builder = 
 DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        InputStream stream = new 
 URL("http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp").openStream();
        Document document = builder.parse(stream);
        Element valCurs = document.getDocumentElement();
        String date = valCurs.getAttribute("Date");
        NodeList valuteList = valCurs.getChildNodes();

        for (int i = 0; i < valuteList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node valute = valuteList.item(i);
            if (valute instanceof Element) {
                Element valuteElement = (Element) valute;
                Valute valuteObject = new Valute();
                NodeList valuteElementList = 
valuteElement.getChildNodes();
                for (int j = 0; j < valuteElementList.getLength(); j++) {
                    Node valuteProperty = valuteElementList.item(j);
                    if (valuteProperty instanceof Element) {
                        Element property = (Element) valuteProperty;
                        Text textNode = (Text) property.getFirstChild();
                        String text = textNode.getData().trim();
                        if (property.getTagName().equals("num_code"))
                            valuteObject.setNum_code(text);
                        else if (property.getTagName().equals("CharCode"))
                            valuteObject.setChar_code(text);
                        else if (property.getTagName().equals("Nominal"))
                            valuteObject.setNominal(text);
                        else if (property.getTagName().equals("Name"))
                            valuteObject.setName(text);
                        else if (property.getTagName().equals("Value"))
                            valuteObject.setValue(text);
                    }
                }
                valuteValues.add(valuteObject);
            }
        }

        model.addAttribute("valuteValues", valuteValues.toString());

            Connection connection = 
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/smartsoft? 
user=postgres&password=alberto&ssl=false");
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("insert into 
valute (num_code, char_code, nominal, name," +
                "value) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        for (Valute valuteValue : valuteValues) {
            ps.setString(1, valuteValue.getNum_code());
        ps.setString(2, valuteValue.getChar_code());
        ps.setString(3, valuteValue.getNominal());
        ps.setString(4, valuteValue.getName());
        ps.setString(5, valuteValue.getValue());
            ps.executeUpdate();
        }
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "main";
}
}

 А вот html:

 

<head>
<title>Spring Security Приложение</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1 th:inline="text">Hello [[${#httpServletRequest.remoteUser}]]!</h1>
<form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Выйти"/>
</form>
<h1>Welcome!</h1>

<h1>Курсы валют</h1>

<table border="5">

<tr>
    <th>num_code</th>
    <th>char_code</th>
    <th>nominal</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>value</th>
</tr>

<tr th:each="valuteValue : ${valuteValues}">
    <td th:utext="${valuteValue}">num_code</td>
    <td th:utext="${valuteValue}">char_code</td>
    <td th:utext="${valuteValue}">nominal</td>
    <td th:utext="${valuteValue}">name</td>
    <td th:utext="${valuteValue}">value</td>
</tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Константин а что за ошибка если есть?

Comment: Всё потому что вы выходите в консоль и возращяет 'main'

Answer (score 0):

Для начала

```
     String result ="";
     while (resultSet.next()){
         ....
         result= "  " + resultSet.getString("value");
      }
    return result;
```

А дальше уже видно будет.

Comment: String result = "";
              while (resultSet.next()){
                  result = "<tr>";
                  result ="<td>"+ resultSet.getString("num_code")+"</td>";
                  result ="<td>"+ resultSet.getString("char_code")+"</td>";
                  result ="<td>"+ resultSet.getString("nominal")+"</td>";
                  result ="<td>"+ resultSet.getString("name")+"</td>";
                  result ="<td>"+ resultSet.getString("value")+"</td>";
                 result ="</tr>";
              }
return result;

Comment: вот ошибка:2020-08-06 21:38:09.210 ERROR 14036 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-2] Exception processing template "</tr>": Error resolving template [</tr>], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Comment: Я же не зря для начала сказал без тегов.

Comment: Изменил контроллер и html, должно работать но не работает

Comment: Тогда нужно посмотреть что там. Какие ошибки и прочие

Comment: Теперь объект выводится во вью, но не так как хотелось бы)

Comment: Чтобы так как хотелось нужно разные encode decode смотреть

Answer (score 0):

Сделал hql запрос в репозитории и загрузил из sql таблицы данные во вью.
Измененный контроллер:

```
           ..........................
           ...........................
    Iterable<Valute> valutes = this.valuteRepository.findByValutes();
        model.addAttribute("valutes", valutes);
             ........................
             ........................
```

Вот репозиторий:

```
public interface ValuteRepository extends JpaRepository<Valute, Integer> {
@Query("from Valute")
List<Valute> findByValutes();
```

}

А вот html:

```html
        .................
        .................
<tr th:each="valute : ${valutes}">
        <td th:utext="${valute.num_code}">num_code</td>
        .......................
        ........................
```